# different URI handling in tomcat VS Wildfly

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot, wildfly-10

I developed my Spring boot application using the embedded tomcat. then i needed it to deploy on Wildfly10.0.0.Final

the way the two handle the requests is very different it seems

the URL i am hitting in browser is:

```
http://localhost:8181/mywebservices/FinancialTransactions/001/CounterpartyId/111/ClientId/222/MarketIdentifier/MID/SecurityId/333/User/123123

http://<My_TEST_WF_SERVER>:10080/mywebservices/FinancialTransactions/001/CounterpartyId/111/ClientId/222/MarketIdentifier/MID/SecurityId/333/User/123123
```

The console output when i run the spring boot app looks like this , the"Looking up handler method for path"  has the same path as the one above it as it has the context root :

```
> 2018-03-12 16:32:49.996 DEBUG 15252 --- [0.1-8181-exec-1]
> o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name
> 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for
> [/mywebservices/FinancialTransactions/001/CounterpartyId/111/ClientId/222/MarketIdentifier/MID/SecurityId/333/User/123123]
> 2018-03-12 16:32:50.003 DEBUG 15252 --- [0.1-8181-exec-1]
> s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : **Looking up handler method
> for path**
> /mywebservices/FinancialTransactions/001/CounterpartyId/111/ClientId/222/MarketIdentifier/MID/SecurityId/333/User/123123
> 2018-03-12 16:32:50.005 DEBUG 15252 --- [0.1-8181-exec-1]
> s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Returning handler method
> [public com.comp.mywebservices.domain.model.MLResponse
> com.comp.mywebservices.rest.mywebservicesController.getRequestWithGhostURLs(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap<java.lang.String,
> java.lang.String>)] 2018-03-12 16:32:50.005 DEBUG 15252 ---
> [0.1-8181-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        :
> Last-Modified value for
> [/mywebservices/FinancialTransactions/001/CounterpartyId/111/ClientId/222/MarketIdentifier/MID/SecurityId/333/User/123123]
> is: -1
```

The logs in Wildfly look like this and the Looking up handler method for path does not have the context root in wildfly :

```
> 2018-03-12 16:20:40,007 DEBUG
> [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (default task-1)
> DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request
> for
> [/mywebservices/FinancialTransactions/001/CounterpartyId/111/ClientId/222/MarketIdentifier/MID/SecurityId/333/User/123123]
> 2018-03-12 16:20:40,031 DEBUG
> [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping]
> (default task-1) Looking up handler method for path
> /FinancialTransactions/001/CounterpartyId/111/ClientId/222/MarketIdentifier/MID/SecurityId/333/User/123123
> 2018-03-12 16:20:40,034 DEBUG
> [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping]
> (default task-1) Did not find handler method for
> [/FinancialTransactions/001/CounterpartyId/111/ClientId/222/MarketIdentifier/MID/SecurityId/333/User/123123]
> 2018-03-12 16:20:40,035 DEBUG
> [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping]
> (default task-1) Matching patterns for request
> [/FinancialTransactions/001/CounterpartyId/111/ClientId/222/MarketIdentifier/MID/SecurityId/333/User/123123]
> are [/**] 2018-03-12 16:20:40,036 DEBUG
> [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping]
> (default task-1) URI Template variables for request
> [/FinancialTransactions/001/CounterpartyId/111/ClientId/222/MarketIdentifier/MID/SecurityId/333/User/123123]
> are {} 2018-03-12 16:20:40,037 DEBUG
> [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping]
> (default task-1) Mapping
> [/FinancialTransactions/001/CounterpartyId/111/ClientId/222/MarketIdentifier/MID/SecurityId/333/User/123123]
> to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [ResourceHttpRequestHandler
> [locations=[ServletContext resource [/], class path resource
> [META-INF/resources/], class path resource [resources/], class path
> resource [static/], class path resource [public/]],
> resolvers=[org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver@64e7e2df]]]
> and 1 interceptor 2018-03-12 16:20:40,038 DEBUG
> [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (default task-1)
> Last-Modified value for
> [/mywebservices/FinancialTransactions/001/CounterpartyId/111/ClientId/222/MarketIdentifier/MID/SecurityId/333/User/123123]
> is: -1 2018-03-12 16:20:40,040 DEBUG
> [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (default task-1)
> Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name
> 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request
> handling 2018-03-12 16:20:40,040 DEBUG
> [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (default task-1)
> Successfully completed request
```

I am not sure what is causing this, nmy app works fine when i run it as a Spring boot app locally but i needs to be deployed to a Wildfly for a dependency.

My RestController method  looks like:

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/mywebservices/**"},
            method = RequestMethod.GET,
            produces = {"application/vnd.api+json"} )

    public MLResponse getRequestWithGhostURLs(HttpServletRequest request,
                                             @RequestParam MultiValueMap<String,String> multiParams) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer with some hit and trial. Issue was that i had introduced jboss-web.xml that is also needed for Wildfly and i had defined the context root ( the same one) over there as well so as per wildfly the first one was the context root for the wildfly ( it omitted it) then it was looking for the context root of my Rest Controller in @RequestMapping which was not there so it didnt see it there.. In tomcat/Spring boot, there was only one container context root and no other. So for wildfly my uRL worked like:

```
http://<My_TEST_WF_SERVER>:10080/mywebservices/mywebservices/FinancialTransactions/001/CounterpartyId/111/ClientId/222/MarketIdentifier/MID/SecurityId/333/User/123123
```

it behaved correctly as mywebservices was the context root of the application. As i had only one RestController i didnt get into the issue of multiple context roots in case i annotated my second one with a different or similar one.

So in this case I just removed mywebservices from below OR remove it from the RestController. ( both work, I think removing it from RestController is the right way to go, unless you have more than one Controller then you will append URI mapping value for the controller after ../mywebservices//

```
http://<My_TEST_WF_SERVER>:10080/mywebservices/<controller_defined_uri_value>/FinancialTransactions/001/CounterpartyId/111/ClientId/222/MarketIdentifier/MID/SecurityId/333/User/123123
```

So my jboss-web.xml looked like :

```
<jboss-web>
    <security-domain>java:/jaas/mywebservicessecurity</security-domain>
    <context-root>mywebservices</context-root>

</jboss-web>
```